# Why did the FBI arrest this character?

Tags: plot-explanation, veep

In the finale of Veep, While Selina Meyers was giving her nomination speech in the DNC, we see her aide, Gary, being arrested by FBI agents in the background.

The last conversation between Selina and Gary hinted she is going to screw him in a way but it wasn't clear how.

What was Gary's alleged crime? On what basis did the FBI arrest him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She chose him as her "fall guy". According to [Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/veep-series-finale-explained-1209598), it was

> for the FBI's investigation into the Meyer Fund, which was the only
>   remaining card that could ruin her.

According to [Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/tv/2019/05/12/veep-julia-louis-dreyfus-tony-hale-series-finale-moment/), it was both:

> her scandals with the Meyer Fund and illicit ties to the Chinese
>   government (whom she actively courted to meddle in the election)